# Lz4 tar compression in python for docker images

Tags: python, docker, tar, lz4

currently I am compressing docker images tar file into Lz4 and Un-taring to load again like this in python.. Basically running linux commands in the python. Wants to use LZ4 compression/decompression (has to be tar, other wise docker won't like it) in python. My main goal is achieve super-fast decompression. Needs straight/simple lz4 way to achieve the task.

******* Compress the docker image*************

```
import os

filename = '~/cloudwatch.tar.lz4'
os.system(f'docker save artifactory.xxx.xxx.com/cloudwatch | lz4 -v > {filename}')
```

******* Decompress the tar.lz4 file and load the image*************

```
import os

filename = '~/cloudwatch.tar.lz4'
os.system(f'lz4 -d -v -c {filename}'| docker load')
```

**************************** Current working compression code in python for basic tar file ************************

```
from docker import from_env

file_name = '~/cloudwatch.tar.lz4'
client = from_env()
image = client.images.get("artifactory.xxx.xxx.com/cloudwatch")

 with open(file_name, 'wb') as fw:
     for chunk in image.save():
         fw.write(chunk)
```

**************************** Current working decompression code in python for basic tar file ************************

```
from docker import from_env

client = from_env()
file_name = '~/cloudwatch.tar.lz4'
 
with open(file_name, 'rb') as fl:    # must be open as bytes
  from_env().images.load(fl)
```

Comment: What problem are you running into?  How have you tried to resolve it so far?  It looks like you already have the images in a private registry; do you need to save/load the image to a file, or can you use `docker pull` to get the image directly from your Artifactory instance?

Comment: there is specific use case where we need to download top 10 images in some Jenkins instances and use it quickly.. so far I tried many python lz4 libraries (http://lz4.github.io/lz4/) .. there is no straight forward methods that I saw can ve used